# Angular 5 Redirect To Same route with QUERY PARAMETERS?

Tags: angular

I am doing searching in angular 5 and stuck on the point, that when i navigate on the same route with different query parameters the component not reinitilize again. I have also listened the change but can only done with parameters not query parameters.

Comment: are you listening changes of QueryparamsMaps or paramMap or both from ActivatedRoute? https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Yes I have tested both of these but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the query parameters too like this:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let myParam = params["myParam"];
});
```

With the route in your constructor like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```